# Inverter - parallel DC link capacitor bank ripple current rating

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, inverter, ripple-current

I'm sizing the DC link capacitors for a 3-phase, 48V, 3kW traction inverter aimed at driving PMSM motors. I'm designing around a minimum ripple current rating of ~50Arms. I'm considering using multiple film caps in parallel, for example the 10uF [B32523Q1106K189](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/epcos-tdk-electronics/B32523Q1106K189/3490019). Voltage ripple is looking like 1% at 10uF so total capacitance won't be a limiting factor.

From the [TDK CLARA](https://captools.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/CLARA/) tool:
[image]

Switching frequency will be 20kHz, and Irms(max) @ 20kHz = 4.953Arms.

Since the parasitics will differ between each capacitor (i.e. ESR), won't each capacitor in the parallel bank both:

1. Have more or less max ripple capacity at 20kHz than the rated value
2. Carry more or less of the total ripple current

Because of this, I don't think it makes sense to just divide the minimum ripple current rating by the individual capacitor ripple current rating, i.e. 50Arms / 4.953Arms = ~10-11 capacitors in parallel (assuming the worst-case condition where all the ripple is in the fundamental frequency).

Considering all of this, how can I analytically estimate how many capacitors I need in parallel to meet the minimum ripple current requirement without doing super extensive simulations (eg. PSIM with sweeps on capacitor parasitics)? Also, how can I estimate the variance in capacitor parasitics?

Note:

1. I calculated the minimum ripple current rating and voltage ripple estimates from this design doc: https://www.specterengineering.com/blog/2019/9/7/dc-link-capacitor-selection-for-your-inverter
2. I'm probably going to select smaller valued capacitors with similar ripple current ratings to optimize space/price, but stuck with one value for the sake of the question.

Comment: Good film capacitors are rated for max dV/dt, so unless your entire capacitor bank has so low capacitance that dV/dt goes above the rated value for the entire bank, you shouldn’t have a problem.

Comment: Have you considered a multi-phase interleaved design? Aluminum polymer types? Why such a low frequency?

Comment: > Have you considered a multi-phase interleaved design?

To clarify, this is a 3-phase traction inverter aimed at driving PMSM motors. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: > Why such a low [switching] frequency?
Need to do some modeling to find the optimal point, but it will end up being a tradeoff between higher frequency (higher cap ripple rating -> fewer caps, lower output THD/motor losses) and lower frequency (lower FET losses - switching, gate charge, dead time, output capacitance, etc.). Looking into using NTMFSC004N08MC switches for now.

Comment: > Good film capacitors are rated for max dV/dt.
Won't exceeding the ripple current rating at a given frequency cause enough heating to damage the capacitor though?

Comment: > Aluminum polymer type [capacitors]? I'll look into this, thanks. I can definitely change the system components, but even if I do that I'm not sure how to estimate the number of capacitors for a given ripple rating at some switching frequency.